Errors in constructing SEM using lavaan package
I’m looking for a second set of eyes to help diagnose the issues I am having with my SEM model:
Here is my SEM code:
sem.model <- '
  #Latent Variables
  latent_edu =~ Education
  

  #Observed Variables
  latent_edu ~ Sexuality_Straight + Racialized_Minority + Age.in.years + Gender_Women + Gender_Minority
  
  Recruit_Online ~ latent_edu + Age.in.years + Sexuality_Straight + Income
    
  Income ~ Gender_Women + Gender_Minority + Sexuality_Straight + Age.in.years + Racialized_Minority
     
  Aware_Yes ~ Age.in.years + Recruit_Online + Sexuality_Straight + Racialized_Minority
 
  Test_Yes ~ Age.in.years + Recruit_Online + Sexuality_Straight + Racialized_Minority
   
  #Covariances
  Gender_Women ~~ Sexuality_Straight
  Gender_Minority ~~ Sexuality_Straight
  Sexuality_Straight ~~ Racialized_Minority
  
'
fit <- sem(sem.model, data = imputed_data, ordered = c("Education", "Income"))
summary(fit)

The following errors occur when I include any covariates related to Sexuality_Straight:
Error: lavaan->lav_model():  
   a model parameter is not defined in the LISREL representation latent_edu ~ 
   Sexuality_Straight. Upgrade to latent variables or consider using 
   representation = 'RAM'.

I created a latent variable for education because the error suggested it. The same error was occurring when I was just using Education, and creating the latent variable does not fix it.
When adding representation = 'RAM', i get this error:
   RAM representation is not (yet) supported for categorical endogenous 
   variables.

Here is the structure of my data:
 $ Income               : num  5 5 2 1 2 5 4 1 2 5 ...
 $ Age.in.years         : int  43 39 27 30 24 25 28 34 28 38 ...
 $ Education            : num  3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 ...
 $ Racialized_Minority  : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ White                : num  1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ Recruit_Online       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Recruit_InPersonPaper: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Gender_Men           : num  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Gender_Women         : num  0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ Gender_Minority      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ Sexuality_Straight   : num  1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ Sexuality_Minority   : num  0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ Aware_Yes            : num  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ Aware_No             : num  1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Test_Yes             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ Test_No              : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 ...

Where am I going wrong here? The variables were previously categorical so i created dummy variables (which you see above). Additionally, Education and Income are ordinal, so these have been converted to numeric and ordered = c("Education", "Income") was included into the model to account for this. The issues occur when including those covariances, without them the model generates.

My guess is that the issue is you specifying: ordered = c("Education", "Income") - which tells lavaan these two variables are categorical.

Thanks for your comment Preston. Intuitively that makes sense, and have tried rerunning without that specification. However, the only time the model does not run is when those covariance terms are included.

Is it possible for you to share a reproducible example?

I believe the issue is with your outcomes (e.g., latent_edu) being binary. I don't think lavaan supports binary endogenous variables except in CFA. Try asking the lavaan google group: https://groups.google.com/g/lavaan
